# valign='middle' working, but not showing correctly text still appears as 'bottom'

Tags: html, css, html-table

Using `valign='middle'` on a `<td>` is working correctly, however, it's not showing "in the middle" it appears as I am using `valign='bottom'`.

The reason I know it is correctly setup is because `valign='top'` does show the text correctly at the top of the table.

I have tried removing line-height from the `<td>` by using `style='line-height: 0;'` but this did not change anything, text still appears at the bottom.

I am out of options to try and searched the first 3 google pages for answers, please do let me know if you know what I am doing wrong here.

Code for reference:

```
...
echo "<tr height='32px'>";
echo "<td width='150px' valign='top'><img src='./images/eye.png' style='height: 32px; width: 32px; margin-right: 10px;'>" . $story->story_extras->view_count . "</td>";
echo "<td valign='top'><img src='./images/camera.png' style='height: 32px; width: 32px; margin-right: 10px;'>" . $story->story_extras->screenshot_count . "</td>";
echo "</tr>"
...
```

Comment: Please don't use presentational attributes, such as `valign` and `width`/`height`.

Comment: because presentational attributes have been replaced by CSS and are deprecated if not obsoleted in newer versions of the HTML specification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either make the `<img>` as block.

```
td img { display: block; }
```

Or add the alignment to the `<img>` tag.

```
td img { vertical-align: middle; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are specifying that the cell should be vertically aligned but it's full. What you want is the image to be vertically aligned in the middle of the text so you should add `align='middle'` to your `<img>` tag.